# How to install MongoDB.Driver in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 trying to install MongoDB.Driver package in my project(.NET Framework 4.6) and I got the following error:

> Invalid static method invocation syntax:
>   "[MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform('Windows')".  Method
>   '[MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform' not found. Static method invocation should
>   be of the form:  $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g.
>   $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).
>   C:\ProjectPath\packages\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.1.0.0\build\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.targets

I tried installing in others projects and repairing visual studio but it didn`t work.

Comment: Still having this issue with VS 2019... net4.8 project. no idea what's happening. solutions below don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share my experience：
2020年1月6日 07:27:40

when i used

```cs
Install-Package MongoDB.Driver
```

in my project(.NET Framework 4.6.1)

Package Manager Console print:

> Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform('Windows')". Method '[MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform' not found.

I just restart my  vs2015 ,I try install this package by

```cs
Install-Package MongoDB.Driver -Version 2.5.0
```

i successed!

Answer (score 1):

There is condition check added in Project file. You can remove that error condition and build should work

```
</PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.1.0.0\build\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.1.0.0\build\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Removed the condition from project file and then worked

```
 <!--<Import Project="..\packages\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.1.0.0\build\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.1.0.0\build\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.targets')" />-->
```

Comment: I removed the Import and target sections which worked.

Comment: The error doesnt happen during the build, it happens when you try installing it from the Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the lastest version(MongoDB.Driver Version 2.10) can`t be installed in Visual Studio 2013, so the solution is to install a previous version that was compatible with Visual Studio 2013.In this case the lastest compatible is version 2.9.3

I had to install a previous version with Package Manager Console using the command :

> Install-Package MongoDB.Driver -Version 2.9.3

In order to open  Package Manager Console you need to go to :

> Tools > NuGet Package Maneger > Package Manager Console